# Workflow action SendEmail does not use "From" field

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2010 workflow for a SharePoint 2010 Server. It uses the default workflow action "SendEmail" to send an e-mail. Everything works out perfectly, but the sender of the e-mail is not the address I set in the "From" property of the "SendEmail" action ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The From address of emails sent from workflow is fixed to the address set in Central Administration and can not be changed.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx#BM9

> **The following options are not
>   supported by the current version of
>   the Send an Email action:**
>
> Specifying
>   an address on the From line. E-mail
>   messages sent by the workflow always
>   show the e-mail address specified by
>   the server administrator on the From
>   line. Only the server administrator
>   can change this, and it can only be
>   changed for all notifications in the
>   current Web application, not per
>   workflow.

There is a project on Codeplex ([spdactivities > Send Email Extended](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/)) that allows you to do this.

Alternatively you can send mail using .net's [system.net.mail](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) without these restrictions

Comment: Ok, thanks. Answers my question but leaves me wondering again, why the action has this property then ... ftw Microsoft ...

Comment: Do you mean WTF or WTF? ;)

Comment: Doh - FTW or WTF! http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ftw

Comment: Is this is same for Visual Studio WF? as the OP states he is using a VS workflow and not an SPD workflow...

Answer (score 2):

Is the sender of the email the 'From' address you specified in the Outgoing Email Settings in SharePoint? This should work - I have used the SendEmail action quite a few times with no issues.

Comment: Yes, it is the address specified in the Outgoing Email Settings. But it is NOT the address set in the "From" property of the workflow action.