# Changing From Email Address in SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflows

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, email

For SharePoint 2007 there was a third-party addon we could install to allow the from email address to be configured in a SharePoint Designer workflow.

Does anyone know if there is something similar for SharePoint Designer 2010 workflows?  I have not been able to find one.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi John, may I know the third-party addon for SharePoint 2007 that allow the "From email address" to be configured in a SharePoint Designer workflow?

Comment: Related: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10055/workflow-action-sendemail-does-not-use-from-field

Comment: @Tom Molskow
Would you mind sharing the code you implemented for modifying the From: field in 2010 workflows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never tried it but this looks promising:

[Useful Sharepoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/)

> NEW! Send Email Extended - Enhaced version of the OOTB activity.
>   Allows you to specify the sender. Also does not break links in body.

Comment: But... Is it working on SharePoint 2010?

Comment: It is not clear but: http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/discussions/270378. so I think it will work. Anyway as I stated in my answer - I never used it ...

Comment: Hi, i just checked it in SharePoint 2010. I worked .. :)

Comment: I had used this on 2007, but from all indications I had seen previously it wasn't supposed to work with 2010.  However, I installed it via PowerShell and it worked perfectly.  :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no Out of box activity to change the from address in email using SharePoint designer

Comment: Right, that's the purpose of the question.

Comment: Vote down is a bit harsh. The original question referred to 2007 and was looking for something similar for 2010. It's not unreasonable to consider whether 2010 has this functionality built in.

Comment: the solution in this link works for even SP2010 http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the CodePlex Send Email Extended workflow activity and I am now using it in SPS 2010 for several SPD 2010 workflows - there have not been any issues.  Please LMK if you would like the code and I can make it available through my Sky Drive.