# how to remove site name from the "from" of an email

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

My requirement is that I have to remove site name EAR which is automatically coming in Email. In place of that I have to keep Name of a person using workflows.

It is coming like- EAR
so I have to remove EAR and give name.

Is it possible in designer?

Comment: If you don't provide any FROM address(sender), then the system automatically uses the site name as sender

Comment: So where to give "From" address of mail?

Comment: This [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10055/workflow-action-sendemail-does-not-use-from-field) might help you